# How to find duplicate Input With MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
`id` `customer_name`  `soundex_code`
 291  F.S. Hosting     F2352
 1509 FS hosting       F2352
 9331 R  Schmit        R253
 9332 R Schmit         R253
```

I Want

```
`id` `customer_name`  `soundex_code`
 291  F.S. Hosting     F2352

 9331 R  Schmit        R253
```

Comment: Do you want to find duplicate inputs or just remove duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id = (select min(id) from table t2 where t2.soundex_code = t.soundex_code);
```

Be careful depending on soundex.  Many names have the same soundex value, using the standard algorithm.